# Android Studio Emulator Frozen and Wrong Phone

Tags: android-studio

Using *Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3* on *Windows 10*, using *Android Virtual Device*.

When attempting to run any app, it shows a phone screen that only displays the google logo animation, the static google logo, or the home screen. None of these react to any of my inputs or interactions. For some reason, the phone is also not the one I selected for emulation. It doesn't look like either the *Galaxy Nexus API 29* or *Pixel 2 API 30*, for example.

No errors appear in Android Studio, though it does say "Waiting for target devices to come online" with the progress bar not moving.

I've tried multiple different emulators, different projects with different settings, I restarted, etc. but nothing seems to work.

[image: frozen emulator screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is actually Cold Boot: Snapshot doesn't exist, which was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49269814/android-emulator-gives-error-cold-boot-snapshot-doesnt-exist). To fix it go to AVD manager -> edit this AVD -> Show Advanced Settings -> Emulated Performance -> Boot Option -> Quick Boot. 
This error message didn't show up until I reinstalled Android Studio, which is why I missed it at first.